# Formal-sounding substitute for "stuck at"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Here is the sentence I'm working with:

> Product manufacturing has (been) ________ (at) one unit per month for
> nearly a year.

Clearly, if just any old word/phrase would do, we could insert "stuck at":

> Product manufacturing has been **stuck at** one unit per month for
> nearly a year.

I also considered "limited to," but it oddly seems too out of place as well: there is no regulation or anything from keeping product manufacturing from going above one, it's purely a discretionary decision.

Is there a more formal-sounding substitute for "stuck-at" I can use here?

Comment: *Product manufacturing rates have held to one unit per month for nearly a year.*

Comment: If it’s on purpose *held* might work. If it’s a hurdle they just can’t seem to get over maybe *has been stalled at*   But I’d note that *stuck at* implies a hurdle-like impediment, while later you say it’s discretionary which is more like it’s being held on purpose.  So which is it?

Comment: @Jim Perhaps you are right that "stuck" has that kind of implication. The actual cause will be a black box I guess, but what is known is that it's not a statutory limitation. "Held" might work, only issue I could find was it loses some of the "slow" connotation. I'm still experimenting.

Comment: Actually, I would probably use *at*: _Product manufacturing rates have held **at** one unit per month for nearly a year._ *Held* is a so-called ergative or middle voice verb here. The rates seem to do the verb *held*, yet we must imagine that an unspecified agent caused it. Compare that to the passive voice *held*: _Product manufacturing rates have **been** held [by inept managers or by old machines] at one unit per month for nearly a year._ (*Stalled* might work instead of *held*, if you can tolerate something slightly less formal.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Product manufacturing has *remained* at one unit per month for nearly a year.